# Devise/Omniauth/FB not signing in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why my Omniauth is not signing users into my app. When I click sign in with facebook, it is sending me back to the root path instead of the @user page. It looks like it is registering a new user when it hits the Users::OmniauthCallbacksController, but the created user has a user_id of null. Does anyone see where I may be going wrong here?

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
   @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
   @user.save
   sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :awards
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 
"users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users do
  resources :cars
  end
  resources :cars

  root 'welcome#home'

end
```

from omniauth method

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
```

Comment: post `from_omniauth` method in user.rb to question

Comment: edit made, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your `facebook` method of `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController`. Make use of [**`persisted?`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F)

```
def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"]) 

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end
```

> Make sure you are getting email from facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried this and it redirected me to the user sign in page unfortunately.

Comment: This means somehow, user object is not being created.

Comment: have you created migration for  `provider` and `uid` field in user model.

Comment: Yep, they are in the schema

Comment: I ended up having to create a new app on the FB developer console and it worked after that. FB was not sending over an email. All resolved now though, thanks for your help!